# JQgrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I wanted to write a code for JQgrid in asp.net .I have tried the same in asp.net MVC,but i want it now in asp.net .
In MVC we use Helper class,and return json data,so what to do in asp.net where helper class can not be used.
Serialization can be done with data to get it in json.,but what about Htmlhelper.
Suggest me  and guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net webforms and asp.net mvc are two different things.

You should not go for exact conversion from mvc to webforms, rather checkout the webforms samples available on jqGrid website.

Here is the [jqGrid Webforms demo](http://trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In my former project we used the standard .js external files and included these in our pages where we needed it (or in a master page to have it in only one place). You can download it here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6.

You can either pay for a control that wraps jqGrid in a control and use that of course. This eases up ASP.NET webforms development if you don't like to fiddle around with jQuery/javascripting.

Comment: I ahve tried jqgrid in asp.net ,the grid is displayed but data is not displaying in it.
I am returning json data.and in url of jquery call i have called aspx page fom where i am getting json data.
But the grid is blank,though the control is entering into that aspx page but ,grid does not show any data.
and there is not error while executing or even in error console.
I am not getting what to do?

Comment: Did you first try with some simple json you have in your page and bind directly to that? If that works then look further down on the retrieval part of that json. You can use tools like `firebug` to see what's getting sent back to the browser. If it doesn't work make a new thread or edit this question and show the relevant code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the jsonReader and specifying the datatype to json?

```
jQuery("#gridid").jqGrid({
 datatype:'json',
 jsonReader : {
    root: "rows",
    page: "page",
    total: "total",
    records: "records",
    repeatitems: true,
    cell: "cell",
    id: "id",
    userdata: "userdata"},
```